# Unity - How to add GameObjects to an array and attach RigidBody2D so they move up and down

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, foreach

I would like to add few objects (prefabs) (tagged: MovingCloud) (quantity is different from scene to scene). Script is attached to this prefab.
I would like all these clouds being detected and move up and down. I tried with arrays but don't know how to make it work.

```cs
GameObject[] clouds;
GameObject cloud;
Rigidbody2D rb;

float cloudSpeed = 2f;
void Start () {
    clouds = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("MovingCloud");

    foreach (GameObject cloud in clouds) {
        var rb = cloud.GetComponent  <Rigidbody2D> ();
    }
}

void FixedUpdate () {
    if (transform.position.y < - 3f) {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2 (0, cloudSpeed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
foreach (GameObject cloud in clouds) 
{
    var rb = cloud.GetComponent  <Rigidbody2D> ();
}
```

This line will just keep reassigning your `rb` variable, not make reference to each clouds `Rigidbody`

---

Looking at your code, I don't think this the right thing to do. 
From your question I think you want clouds to move up and down over time?

From the code you've supplied, it looks like you're trying to control every single cloud from a central script.

I would suggest adding the following script to you `Cloud` prefab, that way each cloud will move independantly!

Attach this to your cloud prefab:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Cloud: MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float speed;

    void Start()
    {
        // Change the speed direction every 5 seconds
        InvokeRepeating("ChangeSpeedDirection", 5f, 5f);
    }

    void Update() 
    {
        // Move this GameObject
        transform.position += new Vector3(0f, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
    }

    void ChangeSpeedDirection()
    {
        speed *= -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: No problem! :-)